# Blit images on top of one another in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I am relatively new to pygame (and also terrible) so naturally I am having many problems. One of which is using images. How would I go about "layering" images in PyGame? I have searched and come to the conclusion that surfaces may help, but I can't seem to figure out how to use them. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm simply trying to blit an image *above* my sprites, but the sprites always end up on the top of the image.

I have attempted to fill the screen before blitting the image, but it didn't work.

```
    display.fill((0,0,255))
    display.blit(pygame.transform.scale(teacher_image, (500,500)),(150,200))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: first you have to use `convert_alpha` to work with colors `(R,G,B,A) ` where `A` means `Alpha`/`Transparency`

Comment: @furas I'm not sure why I need to do that?

Comment: without `alpha` one image will replace all pixels in other image. With `alpha` you can use transparent PNG - without `alpha` it will treat this PNG like normal image with not-transparent background

Comment: some [examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/transparency/complex-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of images, known as "z-order", is simply controlled by the order they are drawn to the screen.

Think of the first image as being draw with a z-order of 0, whereas later images are draw with a higher z-order, so they lay on top of the previous images.

It's possible to change the various image's z-order by changing the ordering of the calls to `blit()`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue - I just needed to update the screen haha

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).